# how to post jquery dyanmic multiple dropdown values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hey anybody can help me out how to fix this problem. I want post generated multiple dropdown values in jQuery to another page but it posting last generated dropdown values. It's not posting all drop down values please any one suggest me how to fix it.

### Below is my working code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      
        $(document).ready(function() {  
           
            $('#num_cat').change(function(){
               

                var num = $('#num_cat').val();                  

                var i = 0;
                var html = '';  
               
                for (i=1;i<=num;i++) {
                html += 'Category ' + i + ': <select name="cat">\n\
               <option value="1"> 1</option>\n\
               <option value="2"> 2</option >\n\
               <option value="3"> 3</option>\n\
               <option value="4"> 4</option>\n\
               <option value="5">> 5</option>\n\
               <option value="6"> 6</option>\n\
               <option value="7"> 7</option>\n\
               <option value="8"> 8</option>\n\
               <option value="9"> 9</option>\n\
               <option value="10"> 10</option>\n\
        </select><br/>'; 
                }
            
                $('#catList').html(html);
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php" onchange="addField(this.value)">
        Number of fields required:      
        <select id="num_cat" name="num_cat">
            <option value="0">- SELECT -</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>

        </select>

        <div id="catList"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
   echo $_POST['cat'];
 
}

?>
```

Comment: fairly certain the `<form>` element doesn't receive an `onChange` event.  That only changes when the elements `value` changes which form does not have.

Comment: He has `$("#num_cat").change(...)` to do the update.

Comment: check link of fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fXMmb/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
                html += 'Category ' + i + ': <select name="cat[]">\n\
```

By using a name ending with `[]`, PHP will make an array of all the values of the different dropdowns. `$_POST['cat']` will be an array, so you should do:

```
var_dump($_POST['cat']);
```

to see all of them.

Comment: but how can i post it in php for storing values into  variables

Comment: If you do what I wrote, it will post them all to PHP, and they will each be an element of the `$_POST['cat']` array.